# Tomcat 7 fails when starts in Debian, but continue working in background

Tags: tomcat, docker, debian, tomcat7

When I run any debian image in docker

```
sudo docker run -it debian /bin/bash
```

install tomcat 7

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y tomcat7
```

and start it, I get

```
/etc/init.d/tomcat7 start
[FAIL] Starting Tomcat servlet engine: tomcat7 failed!
```

But if I open it in browser, I see, that **It works !** 
Checking again using CLI

```
/etc/init.d/tomcat7 status
[ ok ] Tomcat servlet engine is not running..
```

And now the only way I can stop it is killing by pid.
Have you ever met that issue before?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I have met this issue before. Docker is not an init system. The init scripts for sysv and upstart likely require the system to have a proper init system or required daemon running to manage the service.

The script likely runs the actual process, but since there is a lack of init system, misses management bits required for proper status (locating the process PID, restarting, etc).

In this case, it is better to just run the application as your command. See the official Tomcat image for an example: https://github.com/docker-library/tomcat/blob/master/7-jre8/Dockerfile

Comment: If I use any Ubuntu image instead, tomcat is working fine. Could it be that some package or config setting is missing?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. I would compare https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-debian/blob/dist/jessie/build.manifest and https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/dist/trusty/ubuntu-trusty-core-cloudimg-amd64.manifest. At first glance, `init-system-helpers` and `upstart` stand out as differences.